# jQuery can't get data-* attribute value, return undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twig

Sup, I have problem with getting data-* value using jQuery.

My HTML code is:

```
<button type="button" 
   class="btn btn-danger"
   id="{{ currency.id }}"
   data-curname="{{ currency.name }}"
   data-toggle="modal"
   data-target="#deleteConfirm"
   onclick="deleteCurConf(this.id)">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
   &nbsp;Delete
 </button>
```

jQuery is:

```
function deleteCurConf(id) {
 var curName = $('#' + id).data('curname');
 console.log(curName);
}
```

But console log returns undefined. And the most interesting thing that this code was working yesterday but today it's broken. 
 Any idea?

Btw, I'm using Bootstrap3 and Twig

Answer (score 2):

Two little changes needed:

1) just pass `this` instead of `this.id` while calling function:

```
<button type="button" 
   class="btn btn-danger"
   id="{{ currency.id }}"
   data-curname="{{ currency.name }}"
   data-toggle="modal"
   data-target="#deleteConfirm"
   onclick="deleteCurConf(this)">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
   &nbsp;Delete
</button>
```

2) in function:

```
function deleteCurConf(id) {
 var curName = $(id).data('curname'); // use $(id)
 console.log(curName);
}
```

Comment: Finally it works:) Thank's a lot:) Maybe do you know why this code worked yesterday, although there was an error?

Comment: OK, it doesn't matter:) Thanks a lot for help, sorry I don't have enough of ranking here to vote for your answer, so +1 for you here :)

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner way to do in jQuery would be:

```
   <button type="button" 
   class="btn btn-danger handleClick"  // Added extra class
   id="{{ currency.id }}"
   data-curname="{{ currency.name }}"
   data-toggle="modal"
   data-target="#deleteConfirm"       
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
   &nbsp;Delete
 </button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("document").on("click",".handleClick",function(evnt){

 var curName = $(evnt.target).data('curname'); // use $(id)
 console.log(curName);

})
```